Text Transformation : train a model to generate output files from input files
I'm currently working on a project that consists of "translating" files from one format to another, I used the programming approach with a mapping that links each pattern from the input file with the convenient one in the output, its quite hard to write the mapping and the class that does the translation, in addition, I should write a new one each time I want a new format or a tweak, so I decided to replace the whole thing with a model that can be tried with thousands of input files and their respective output, here's a small example to give you an idea :
chunk from input file :
DIM+1.800:0.400:500:CT+12
That converts to XML tags in the output as :
 <height>1.800<\height>
    <length>0.400<\length>
    <width>500<\width>


So basically, the first line is what we call a "segment", it starts with a 3 letters Acronym, as you can see it stands for dimensions here and it convert the height length and width as shown, the input files are a series of segments like dimension, date, address and things like that, the output could be an XML or something else but I guess the model's logic wont be very different and I could just tweak it for other formats, all I need for now is XML, how can this be done???
I'm very new to Machine learning, but I've been a developer for enough time, so I tried a rigid approach.
